# Value not changed after edit in datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I created an instance of `DataGridView` to display a dataset. I made the 8th column editable. However, when I edit this column and go to another column/cell, the value has not changed.

Can anyone help me solve this problem. I am a new to VB.NET.

Comment: Please post your code .

Comment: How do you check `the value has not changed`

Answer (score 0):

In your datagridview validating event add this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Validating( .... ) Handler ....

    e.Cancel = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @user2463128 : There's no param .. just add **e.Cancel = False** in your Datagridview Validating Event ...